# Is there a pytable equivalent of sql 'like' and 'not like'

Tags: sql, pytables

I have created a table in pytable. I need a equivalent condition in pytables for

select * from table_name where col_name like '%new%'
select * from table_name where col_name like 'new%'

And also how to do this if the column is an integer datatype?

i am able to do this 
rows = tb1.read_where("col_name==16")
But not able to use "like"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly in a PyTables / numexpr query.  String comparisons basically are limited to numeric-like operations (`==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, etc).  You need to do the LIKE evaluation in python, probably with regular expressions.  Here is what I would do:

```
import re
import tables as tb

new_re = re.compile('new')
with tb.open_file(...) as f:
    tb1 = f.root.tb1
    rows = [row[:] for row in tb1 if new_re.search(row['col_name']) is not None]
```

This has the advantage of only reading through the data once.  Note that if you only care about columns starting with new (`new%`) you may be able to get away with the following due to ASCII ordering.

```
rows = tb1.read_where('col_name >= "new" & col_name < "nex"')
```